# VLookup to add a name to UserForm textbox531 when an employee number is added to userform Combobox9

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to have on my UserForm, in Excel 2010, to do a VLookup to another worksheet in the same workbook. Basically when I type an employee number in my combobox9 box and press enter, I want the name to be filled in by the VLookup into the `textbox531` box. This is what I have so far and I feel the VLookup is not working. It doesn't do anything in the `textbox531` box. It gives me nothing in the `textbox531`. "Officer" is the name of the range on worksheet "Tables". Any guidance?

```
Private Sub TextBox531_Change()
    'Dim LName1 As String
    LName1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox9.Value, Worksheets("Officers").Range("Officers"), 2, False)
    TextBox531.Value = LName1
    MsgBox (LName1)
End Sub
```

[image: tables]

Comment: I am very new to VBA so I might have made an error somewhere. My range is correct. Column 1 has the employee number and column 2 had the last name (Lname).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub ComboBox9_Change()
Dim sht As Worksheet, cmbVal As Double
    Set sht = Worksheets("Tables")
    cmbVal = Me.ComboBox9.Value
    TextBox531.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cmbVal, sht.Range(Officers), 2, False)
    Set sht = Nothing
End Sub
```

@George I was getting the same runtime error because the datatype was not matching you will need to make sure the datatype you are giving to the Vlookup matches the datatype in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Clint, I will put that in my ComboBox9 which will input the employee numbers and then my text box531 will pop the name in when i press enter from the combobox9 box?  Also I replace your Sheet1 with Tables and adjust my range alon with changing textbox1 to textbox531?

Comment: Yes George I changed the names so it should work for you. I gave Taylor an up vote because his answer is basically the same as mine just without the correct data type.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem most likely is that your sub is tied to TextBox531_Change(), when it sounds like you're wanting it to be tied to combobox9_Change().

Try changing the code to

```
Private Sub combobox9_Change()
Dim LName1 As String
LName1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox9.Value, Worksheets("Officers").Range("Officers"), 2, False)
TextBox531.Value = LName1
MsgBox (LName1)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting   Run-time error'9':   Subscript out of range.    What does that mean?

Comment: You mentioned that the worksheet is named "Tables", try changing to: `LName1 = WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(ComboBox9.Value, Worksheets("Tables").Range("Officers"), 2, False)`

Comment: I missed that Tables. But now I am getting this error: Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: That means that the entered value was not found in the range. If it should have been found, check that it's spelled the same in both locations. Otherwise you can stop it from popping up error messages if something isn't found by adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to the start of the sub and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` to the end of the sub.

Comment: Thanks for helping but there is something else going on. When I run the userform and the focus is on combobox9, I start to type and it immediately gives me the error. So it wont even get close to the vlookup. The spelling is correct by the way.

Comment: Well, the good news is we're making progress. What's happening is because this code is tied to `_Change()`, which means the second you put a character in the combobox, you've made a change and triggered the macro. You could add a button to the userform to click once you've entered a name. Call the button something like "FindButton", then your code should be something like `Private Sub FindButton_Click()`

Comment: OK you lost me in the the later part of your comment. I can add a button on the userform and the rest I can sum up as "huh?"

Comment: Add the button to the userform, then right click it and select "View Code". This should take you to the code editing window, focused on a line with something like `Private Sub YourButtonNameHere_Click()`. Cut and paste the code from your current sub into this new sub. That changes the trigger from being an edit to Combobox9 to being a click on the button you create.

Comment: I'm about to throw the towel in. I feel I am taking up too much of your time. I am geting the error again--- Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class.

Comment: One last check then: The named range "Officers" does include the last names you're trying to return, as well as the employee numbers, correct? And those names are in the second column of the range "Officers", not necessarily the second column of the spreadsheet?

Comment: see attached picture in my original post. I just added it

Comment: I accidentally cut off the column letters. Yes the Star column is A and LastName is column B.

Comment: And Range("Officers") incorporates both columns A and B?

Comment: actually range Officers incorporates A2 to D300